# Trigger click on embedded video when page loads

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-listener

I have noticed there are a few questions that have been asked on the above topic, however, there hasn't been one for embedded videos. I was hoping someone would be able to help.

Note: My first post - so apologies if i haven't provided the appropriate information!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".container-fluid").on('click','#issuuclick',function(){
           alert("it's working") 
        })
        
});

</script>
```

```html
<div data-configid="26360926/39969074" style="width:525px; height:373px;margin: 0 auto;" class="issuuembed" id="issuuclick"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="//e.issuu.com/embed.js" async="true"></script>
```

the above is my html embedded and javascript code. The aim here is to automatically open the publication in full spread when the page loads but only the alert is popping up at the moment (I have used a timer).

Would appreciate some assistance!

Comment: It's not really clear what your intention is. Do you want to attach a click handler to "#issuuclick" or do want to simulate a click on "#issuuclick" on pageload? Or both?

Comment: I would like to simulate a click on #issuuclick on pageload.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#issuuclick").trigger("click");
});

//or

window.onload = function() {
    $("#issuuclick").trigger("click");
};
```

The first example fires as soon as the document is ready to work with and the second example fires when the page is ready and ALL resources are loaded

And attach a click handler to "#issuuclick" like

```js
$(document).on("click", "#issuuclick", function(){
    // do something
});
```